# JAXB External Custom Binding XJC Issue - Parsing results in empty node

Tags: jaxb, xjc

Forgive me if this is a duplicate. Here is my binding.xjb file. But now i am getting the regular error that the complex type target "AddBankVaultRplyType" is not found. I don't see any issue. Can somebody help me with this? I am listing the xsd that i am trying to customize

```
<jxb:bindings 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:pd="http://chubb.com/cpi/polsvc/xmlobj"
xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance"
jxb:version="2.1"
>


<jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:ServiceReply/xs:complexType[@name='AddBankVaultRplyType']">
<inheritance:extends>com.print.poc.AddressTypeHelper</inheritance:extends>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Here is the piece of XSD that i am trying to customize

```
<xs:schema xmlns:pd="http://com/polsvc/xmlobj" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://com/polsvc/xmlobj" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:complexType name="AddBankVaultRplyType">

</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ServiceReply">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ReplyHeader" type="pd:MsgHeaderType"/>
    <xs:element name="RequestHeader" type="pd:MsgHeaderType"/>
    <xs:choice>
     <xs:element name="AddBankVaultReply" type="pd:AddBankVaultRplyType"/>
</xs:choice>
 </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now if i run XJC it is saying me that the target `"/xs:schema/xs:ServiceReply/xs:complexType[@name='AddBankVaultRplyType']"` results in empty node. What is the mistake i am doing here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to wrap in a bindings that has the schema location set.  It should be something like:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:pd="http://chubb.com/cpi/polsvc/xmlobj"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="your-schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AddBankVaultRplyType']">
            <inheritance:extends>com.print.poc.AddressTypeHelper</inheritance:extends>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

For more information:

- http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_errors.html

Comment: Thanks again. Looks like it works fine but its showing this error.parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?

Answer (score 4):

I finally got mine workign with subclassing as well as adding @XmlRootElement to those dang complexTypes that are used by a root element(I don't get why JAXB doesn't add it for me, but this does the trick of doing that since JAXB doesn't)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd
                    http://annox.dev.java.net "
  jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
  version="2.1">

  <jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    <!-- All generated classes must have MySignature interface (supplied in dependencies) -->
    <xjc:superClass name="com.cigna.framework.DataObject"/>
    <xjc:superInterface name="com.cigna.framework.InterfaceTest"/>
    <!-- All temporal fields are implemented as Joda DateTime and use DateUtils as an adapter -->
    <jaxb:javaType
      name="org.joda.time.DateTime"
      xmlType="xs:time"
      parseMethod="com.cigna.framework.util.DateUtil.stringToDateTime"
      printMethod="com.cigna.framework.util.DateUtil.dateTimeToString"
      />
  </jaxb:globalBindings>



  <!-- Application of annotations to selected classes within schemas -->

  <!-- org.example.SomeRootType @XmlRootElement -->
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/externalaction_2012_03.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings >
        <jaxb:package name="com.framework.action"></jaxb:package>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

  </jaxb:bindings>

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/common_2012_04.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings >
        <jaxb:package name="com.framework.common"></jaxb:package>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='PersonNameType']">
      <annox:annotate>
        <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="SomeRootType"/>
      </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/utilities_2012_03.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings >
        <jaxb:package name="com.framework.util"></jaxb:package>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

  </jaxb:bindings>  

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Of course I struggled with the pom.xml alot but finally came to this solution which worked for me.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-xsd</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>schemas/*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>schemas/*.xjb.xml</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                        </args>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                <version>0.6.3</version>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                <version>0.6.3</version>
                            </plugin>                               
                        </plugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

later,
Dean

Comment: did you use a special maven command to build the classes or just mvn clean package?