# JAXB marking elements as deprecated

Tags: xsd, jaxb

In JaxB, we need to move from one schema form to another and we would love to be able to deprecated stuff in the xsd with some simple note in the xsd:documentation element or something.  Is there a way to get JAXB to mark these generated classes and methods with @Deprecated so developers can easily see which cold still needs to change?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the Annotate plugin: [Annotate plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin)(edit: the original [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120120064728/http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin) is no longer valid).

You'll see a couple of examples, including deprecation, warning suppression, etc.

It is usually recommended to do this stuff using special markup under appinfo as opposed to documentation.

Comment: hmmm, I am getting errors when using that in the xjb file :( :(.  It could add the @XmlRootElement which would be soooo sweeeeet.

Comment: @Petru Gardea The link points to a site that looks like a virus/scamware/spamware site.

Comment: @GC_, thank you. I've replaced the original link with the web archive one and added the GitHub repo instead.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got all of mine working quite nicely...thanks!!!!  The complete code is found here

[JAXB External Custom Binding XJC Issue - Parsing results in empty node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785454/jaxb-external-custom-binding-xjc-issue-parsing-results-in-empty-node/10565944#10565944)