# How to exclude Observable in XSD file generated by JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xmltransient

I have an abstract class extending java.util.Observable. When i generate xsd using Jaxb, there appears a complex type observable in the xsd file.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public abstract class MyClass extends Observable implements Runnable, Serializable
```

I would use @XmlTransient on super type if it was a class i have written. Don't know how to exclude Observable.

I tried creating java.util package with package-info.java class to annotate package, as it was mentioned in this post [JAXB: @XmlTransient on third-party or external super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543823/jaxb-xmltransient-on-third-party-or-external-super-class) :

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.NONE)
package java.util;
```

Did not work. Also tried it with XMLTransient:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient
package java.util;
```

Again no luck. Anyone has any solution for this ?

Comment: The package `java.util` is protected by the JVM, you cannot do anything to it.

Comment: Sigh!! I guess i need to change the design a bit

Comment: Not necessarily. There might be other ways, I just don't know them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that makes two of us :) I guess it is better not to put business logic in xsd objects, and simply use them for data exchange.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can you post your comment as an answer ?